# Getting value from dynamically created inputText box in forEach section

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to do something very similar to this [Getting value from dynamically created inputText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856339/getting-value-from-dynamically-created-inputtext) and i have some difficulties that is why i will ask my question here, hope you can help me. I want to bind dynamically generated input box with Object. I have:

```
<c:forEach items="${filterTypeBean.listTextFilterTypes()}"
                        var="inputBoxes">
                        <h:outputText value="${inputBoxes.filterTypeName}"
                            style="width: 100px; white-space: normal; border: 3px" />
                        <h:inputText value="${requestBean.filterTypeValue}" />
                    </c:forEach>
```

In the request bean for filterTypeValue i have:

```
private String filterTypeValue;

public String getFilterTypeValue() {
    return filterTypeValue;
}

public void setFilterTypeValue(String filterTypeValue) {
    this.filterTypeValue = filterTypeValue;
}
```

My issues come from the fact that i have three entities - TRequest, TRequestFilter, TFilter. TRequestFilter is a mapping table, where i have TREQUEST, TFILTER and the value which i want to take and insert in DB from the inputbox latter.

filterTypeBean.listTextFilterTypes() i take from FilterTypeBean:

```
public List<TFilterType> listTextFilterTypes() {
        EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select u from TFilterType u where u.filterType like 'T'");
        List<TFilterType> resultList = q.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
```

I want to set the value of inputbox in RequestBean because first i insert a new Request in the DB, and after that i want to insert the filters for this new Request in TRequestFilter table (the reason i need TFilter and the inserted value for it).

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it working with mapping in my bean class:

```
private Map<TFilterType, Object> values = new HashMap<TFilterType, Object>();

public Map<TFilterType, Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
```

and iterator:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            if (pairs.getValue() != null) {
                          System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + '='+ pairs.getValue());
            }
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
```

in this way i have and Object and its value and i am able to insert a record in a new Entity in the database.